# Good practice to have a data-only controller in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, application-design

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 and have various controllers in various areas.

In many of these I need to select a value from a list of values contained in a database; selecting a product or an employee for example.

I'm currently thinking of having a controller dedicated to getting these lists of things for use with dropdownlists etc. This controller would simply query the DAL and serve up JSON objects to be loaded with an ajax call on any view that needed them.

My only concern with this is that my view will be getting data from different controllers at once.

Am I right to be concerned? Is there a better way of setting this up, maybe creating a `Product`/`Employee` class especially to create a shared strongly typed partial view from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another class which acts as a middle layer between your controllers and data access code. You can call this class methods from differnt controllers now.

```
public class ItemService()
{
 public static List<Items> GetItems()
 {
    var items=yourRepositary.GetItems();
    return items;
 }
}
```

You can call it from your different controllers now

```
public ActionResult GetItems()
{
  var items=ItemService.GetItems();
  return Json(items,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but aren't I then going to be duplicating the `ActionResult GetItems()` method in any controller that needs it? (I admit it's not much code, so maybe not a problem). My thought is that if I re-create this method in many controllers, why not have all similar methods in a single controller and have every view that needs an ajax list of items just use that controller.

Comment: Ofcourse. If you are looking for a method which is returning list of states, keep a state controller with a GetStates/Idnex action method to return all states. You can call it from different views. But if you want to get the same data in different action methods, introduce a reusable middle tier so taht you can call it from different action methods (one returns json/ another return a ViewModel etc...)

Comment: Ahh ok. I understand what you're saying now. Thanks.

Comment: This is essentially how I would solve the problem.  I use this for caching as well -- since many of my lookups are changed infrequently I put a caching object between my Controller and the Service/DB layer.  The caching layer is specific to web requests in my case meaning I keep the service layer pure (realtime from the database) and allow my website to cache data.  Some may argue that this is "leaky abstraction" but I don't agree.  My website knows what data it requires and how to cache it.  The service knows where to get data and has it's own internal caching rules.

Comment: @kingdango: Totally agree that a caching layer is a good way to reduce db calls. But it still depends on the scenrario. If the data is not being changed very often caching is a must !

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a base class controller that implements this common functionality, then  inherit other concrete controllers (paired with views) from this.

This approach would support a situation where there are lots of different lists, or the lists needed building dynamically in response to input paramters.

The ActionFilterAttribute approach might be better suited to situations where there are fewer, more static lists.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution imho is to create a custom ActionFilterAttribute that populates the ViewData dictionary with whatever data you need to render on the views. You can then create extensions for ViewDataDictionary to access this info in a type-safe manner from the views, or throw an exception if the ViewData does not contain the data (ie prompting you to add the action filter attribute above your controller method). Using inheritance could get you in a mess further up the road.